# Differing feature importances after saving/loading GBT Classification model

Tags: boosting, spark-mllib

I am using the GBTClassifier in Spark's ml.classification package. Right after training my model, I save it, and then I grabbed the feature importances, using

```
featureColumns.zip(gbt.featureImportances.toArray).sortBy(-_._2).take(20).foreach(println)
```

which were something like:

```
(feature_A,0.14660323842333461)                                             
(feature_B,0.13404619432422415)
(feature_C,0.13355431289064645)
(feature_D,0.10644547288325541)
```

after loading the model, I tried to grab the feature importances again, and I got:

```
(feature_C,0.15623812489248929)                                             
(feature_B,0.14782735827583288)
(feature_D,0.11000200303020488)
(feature_A,0.10758923875000039)
```

What could be causing the difference in feature importances? Is it something to do with how Spark works? Or does it mean there's a bug in my code?

For reference, I used the following code for saving and loading:

```
gbt.write.overwrite.save(s"${fileLocation}")
gbt.read.load(s"${fileLocation}")
```